# Storing and fetching nested Json object in db Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to store and fetch the nested JSON object in db. My json will look like this :

```
{
  "itemID": "12841",
  "rfidTag": "IRYS009",
  "itemERPKey": null,
  "skuNumber": "IRYS009",
  "designNumber": "FR001",
  "imageName": "FR001",
  "itemStatus": "InStock",
  "semiFinished": [
    {
      "sfID": "775",
      "sfERPKey": "IRYS009",
      "sfType": "dia"
    },
    {
      "sfID": "776",
      "sfERPKey": "IRYS009",
      "sfType": "ruby"
    }
  ],
  "miscellaneous": [
    {
      "miscellaneousID": "459",
      "miscellaneousERPKey": "IRYS009",
      "miscellaneousType": "dia"
    },
    {
      "miscellaneousID": "460",
      "miscellaneousERPKey": "IRYS009",
      "miscellaneousType": "ruby"
    }
  ]
}
```

I first thought of using no SQL solution Sembast but got to know there is a performance issue with large data set. I need to store more than 60000 records. I also thought of using REALM but no stable package of Realm is available for Flutter.

I then used moor but in this too insertion and fetching of such complex objects are not easy.

Please let me know any possible solution available in flutter for storing and fetching complex JSON objects efficiently and also with 60000 records.

Comment: I have also tried moor but there is no clear documentation of storing and retrieving such nested json objects in moor.

Comment: @Chaitali Jain 60000 records isn't large data set. For NoSQL engines like MongoDB large data set (when you can see a performance issue) is 400M records (400.000.000). So don't worry about performance with your data set and use NoSQL engine.

Comment: Are you trying to store the whole thing as a single string, or decompose it into some normalized table schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out Hive NoSQL Database with flutter, I really believe it encompasses what you are trying to achieve, here is a link to their official documentation
https://pub.dev/packages/hive